# combine Fragment and Activity class in Base class

Tags: java, android, oop, android-fragments

I have 2 classes:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements MyListener
public void myFun1()
public void myFun2()
public void myFun23()

public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyListener
public void myFun1()
public void myFun2()
public void myFun34()
```

I am trying to combine my two classes in an base class so I need to write `myFun1()` and `myFun2()` only once but the problem is that one class extends Fragment and one class extends Activity. How can I bring the functions together in one base class?

EDIT: The methods do not come from the listener and can be ignored. `myFun1()` and `myFun2()` have the same functionality while `myFun23()` and `myFun34()` have both a special function only necessary in its class

Comment: Is `myFun1()` `myFun2()` `myFun23() ` an implementation of interface `MyListener`?

Comment: no its not, maybe the listener was too much and is more confusing than it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this specific situation probably your `myFun1()` and `myFun2()` access some member variables in `MyFragment` and `MyActivity`. If you want to common out (like strategy pattern) the implementation of the `myFun1()` and `myFun2()` you should supply those variables to the common implementation either directly, or indirectly by introducing another interface.

The second solution of introducing another interface is mostly not preferable. In the first solution we end up with a strategy like the following.

```
class DataFetchingStrategy(val repo: Repository) : MyListener {
    fun myFun1() {
      repo.fetchData1()
    }

    fun myFun2() {
      repo.fetchData2()
    }
}
```

A strategy is not a listener. Even though we name it differently like `DataFetcher` or `RepoManager`, they are also not listeners.

Then how can we eliminate the duplicate code from the listener methods? Listener methods should be as lean as possible and the listener implementations should be ad hoc. The listener methods will forward the call to a strategy or delegate or composite etc. Not the strategy or delegate or composite will implement the listener.

```
class DataFetcher(val repo: Repository) {
  fun fetchData1() {
    // implementation
  }

  fun fetchData2() {
    // implementation
  }
}

class MyFragment : Fragment, MyListener {
  val dataFetcher = DataFetcher(Repository())

  fun myFun1() = dataFetcher.fetchData1()

  fun myFun2() = dataFetcher.fetchData2()

  fun myFun23() {}
}

class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity, MyListener {
  val dataFetcher = DataFetcher(Repository())

  fun myFun1() = dataFetcher.fetchData1()

  fun myFun2() = dataFetcher.fetchData2()

  fun myFun34() {}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it only with **Java8** that introduced the `default` methods in interfaces.
You can define something like:

```
public interface MyInterface {

    default void myFun1() {
         // default method implementation
    }

    default void myFun2() {
         // default method implementation
    }

}
```

Then:

```
   public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyListener, MyInterface {

     // Just define
     public void myFun23(){}
   }

   public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements MyListener, MyInterface {

     // Just define
     public void myFun34(){}
   }
```

You can do the same with **kotlin**.

```
interface MyInterface {
    fun myFun1() {
      // implementation
    }
    //...
}
```

Then:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), MyInterface {

    fun func23() {
       //...
    }
}

....
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a rule of thumb in Object Oriented Programming called "Favor Composition over Inheritance". Your question is a classic example of the benefits of composition over inheritance. All you need to do is move the functions into another class and then create an instance of that class wherever you want.

For example:

```
public class MyFunctions {

    public void myFun1() {
        // do cool things here
    }

    public void myFun2() {
        // do cool things here
    }

}

public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements MyListener {
    MyFunctions myFunctions = new MyFunctions();
}
```

To learn more about this rule of thumb and many many more, you should read [Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0134685997).

Answer (score 1):

You could think about Composition over Inheritance or Strategy Patterns.
e.g. your Classes don't implement MyListener but include a MyListener instance

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment 
public MyListener myListener;

public class MyActivity extends BaseActivity 
public MyListener myListener;

public class MyListenerImpl implements MyListener
public myFun1();
public myFun2();
```

you can now use your functions in all classes, that have an instance of it.

(with Kotlin you could simply create the Functions without the need of classes)